Where does One Piece: Gyojin Tou-hen fit in the One Piece continuity?
I watched 100+ episodes of the original One Piece series to see if I could get hooked with it and watch the whole series. It didnt work, but now I want to give it a second chance by watching One Piece: Gyojin Tou-hen, and if I like it (it's only 21 episodes apparently) I probably will resume watching the original series.
But I want to understand where this story fits with the episodes of the original series I've already watched, to understand it better and have more chances to like it.
Where does One Piece: Gyojin Tou-hen fit in the One Piece continuity ?

If you mean the special edited version that will be airing for the next few months, then fandom wiki claims that it's supposed to cover the 57 episodes of the original Fish-Man saga (from right after the time skip). This piece of information seems unsourced (i.e. the source they give does not mention the numbers 21 or 57), but if so then they would be episdes form 517 to 574, minus the filler episode 542.
